# Proof check for uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to show the following.

Let $f_k:A\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be unbounded for each $k \in \mathbb N$ and $f_k$ converge to $f$ uniformly. Then $f$ is also unbounded.

My proof:

Supposed $f_k:A\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is unbounded for each $k \in \mathbb N$ and $f_k$ converge to $f$ uniformly. Since for each $k\in\mathbb N$ $f_k$ is unbounded, for all $M \in \mathbb R$ there is some $x_0\in A$ such that $\left|f_k(x_0)\right|>M+1 \Leftrightarrow \left|f_k(x_0)\right|-1>M$. Also, since $f_k\rightarrow f$ uniformly, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\left|f(x)-f_k(x)\right|<\varepsilon$ for $k\ge N$ and for all $x \in A$.

We also know from the reverse triangle inequality that

$\left|\left|f(x)\right| - \left|f_k(x)\right|\right| \le \left|f(x)-f_k(x)\right|$.

So if we let $\varepsilon = 1$, then for some $N\in \mathbb N$ we have

$\left|\left|f(x)\right| - \left|f_N(x)\right|\right| \le \left|f(x)-f_N(x)\right|<1$

$\Rightarrow \left|\left|f(x)\right| - \left|f_N(x)\right|\right|<1$

$\Rightarrow -1< \left|f(x)\right| - \left|f_N(x)\right| <1$

$\Rightarrow \left|f_N(x)\right|-1 <\left|f(x)\right| $.

Evaluating this at the $x_0$ from earlier, we get

$\Rightarrow \left|f_N(x_0)\right|-1 <\left|f(x_0)\right| $

$\Rightarrow M<\left| f(x_0) \right|$.

Are there any flaws in my proof?

Comment: Why don't you argue by way of contradiction? Assume $f$ is bounded. then $|f_k|\le |f_k-f|+|f|$ would be bounded since $f_k-f$ goes to zero and $f$ is bounded.

Comment: That works as well, I hadn't thought of doing that. This was my first attempt at this proof, so I hadn't explored the other methods of proving.

Comment: For me, sealing with boundedness is easier than unboundedness. Your proof is, more or less, the unbpunded version of my attempt.